# Facebook test users created with one ID but queries return a different ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, testing

I'm creating Facebook test users. This process worked fine in the previous incarnation of the app, but we need to change the app name (and other aspects) and so are migrating everything to a new Facebook app.

I'm creating (using the developer console) some test users, and then using:

https://graph.facebook.com/MY_NEW_APP_ID/accounts/test-users?access_token=SOME_TOKEN

to query for the list of test users.

The trouble is, the above query returns "id" fields with different values from what the developer console shows.

The developer console shows this user ID `100004577959NNN` and a query to http://graph.facebook.com/100004577959NNN returns:

> {
>     "id": "100004577959NNN",
>     "first_name": "Jackdaw",
>     "gender": "female",
>     "last_name": "Two",
>     "link": "https://www.facebook.com/people/Jackdaw-Noster-Two/100004577959NNN",
>     "locale": "en_GB",
>     "middle_name": "Noster",
>     "name": "Jackdaw Noster Two"
>     }

But the `accounts/test-users` query returns an ID of `311068562389MMM`. Then http://graph.facebook.com/311068562389MMM returns:

> {
>   "id": "311068562389MMM",
>   "first_name": "Jackdaw",
>   "gender": "female",
>   "last_name": "Two",
>   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/people/Jackdaw-Noster-Two/100004577959NNN",
>   "locale": "en_GB",
>   "middle_name": "Noster",
>   "name": "Jackdaw Noster Two"
>   }

As you can see, they're the same user... but they have different IDs.

The second user ID is consistently returned (it doesn't vary with different calls to the top query).

The previous incarnation of the app did not show this behavior.  The returned IDs were always consistent with the console IDs.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that 311068562389MMM is the user id and 100004577959NNN is the app scoped user id. Or the other way around.

Comment: @WizKid: Yes, that seems like it might be the issue. Thanks! Will report back once I've dug a bit more.

Comment: @WizKid: Yes, that was it! Many thanks.  Please make your comment an answer, and I'll give you the tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that 311068562389MMM is the user id and 100004577959NNN is the [app scoped user id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids). Or the other way around.